# Branching logic in SharePoint Survey

Tags: survey

My survey has a list of questions for which the required answer is Yes or No. If the answer is No, then there is branching logic to another question which asks the respondent to enter text to explain why they responded No to the previous question (lets call this question Comments)

Once they have typed their answer, I want to be able to branch back to the next question for this respondent. Problem is in the branching logic section for the Comments question, the selection is either No Branching or Content Type. 
Is there a way to bring the respondent back to their next question?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Branching Logic goes in one direction for surveys so you may also have to make the questions or columns with unique names and use page separators to help your branching logic work out how you want it.

This example if you select Yes for question 1 it will jump to question 2.

- Q1 Question 1 [Choice(Yes/No)] - Branching logic if Yes go to (Q2
  Question 2)
- (page separator)
- Q1 If No Explain (multi text)
- (page separator)
- Q2 Question 2 [Choice(Yes/No)]
- (page separator)
- Q2 If No Explain (multi text) - etc...

Experiment with the list a bit to get the hang of it, I usually make all the questions adding page separators along the way and then go back and add my branching logic as I go from start to finish.